# Datatables sDom challenge add new element to bottom left of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add a "refresh" button to my tables at the bottom of the table. But I just started using datatables and its a bit confusing as is the "sDom" part where it says I can do this through that means but the description is vague at best.

```
"sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
```

is the datatables.net example, but I dunno how to make heads or tails of that and all I want to do is one simple thing.

Or is there an outside of "sDom" that would be better suited for what I want to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a live example of a modified `sDom`.

http://live.datatables.net/onaqul/edit#javascript,html,live

Here we're injecting a `div` called `<div id="refresh"></div>` with the structrue `<"#refresh">`.

```
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"<"#refresh">flp><"clear">'
      });
```

If you inspect the generated dom in the example, 
you can see `<div id="refresh"></div>` got inserted inside of `<div class="bottom"></div>`.

I think much depends on (1) how your specific table has its footer elements layed out, (2) where you decide to inject your specific element using [sDom](http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom), and (3) how you style the element(s) with your `CSS`.

Alternatively, you could have a button created outside of the datatables environment, but use jquery to append or prepend your button to one of the dom elements datatables creates.

Hope this is a useful starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you that the DataTables `'sDom'` property is confusing.  Personally I just set `sDom` equal to `'t'`, which creates just the table, and I add any buttons or what have you outside of the DataTables code using jQuery or some other method.  Not much of an answer, but that's what I would do if I were in your situation and wanted to do something simple like add a button.