# jQuery DataTable: dom parameter displays layout differently when setting it manually

Tags: jquery, datatables

Accordingly to [this](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) and [this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) pages (which I used as a reference) I settled the dom parameter for my DataTable because I wanted to remove the pagination function.
This worked, but resulted other additional functionalities to be displayed in different lines .

After this just for make a test, I set the dom parameter to the default value as the referenced website says

> "lfrtip (when bJQueryUI is false) or <"H"lfr>t<"F"ip> (when bJQueryUI
>   is true)"

but it resulted the same:[image: Wrong layout]

When I remove the dom settings completly, the layout become what I expect  with the undesirable pagination:[image: right layout]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759882/datatables-sdom-challenge-add-new-element-to-bottom-left-of-tablehttp://) the asker had a similar problem and the accepted answer was to introduce a special css class. **But I am wondering, why does the default value behave differently when setting it manually**?

*(Using a css class is my only option to resolve the problem?)*

```
        $scope.dataTable = $("#ttable").DataTable({
            "sorting": [[2, "desc"]],
            "data": $scope.tTable,
            "language": { "sUrl": $scope.dataTableTranslation },
            "autoWidth": false,
            "columns": $scope.tTableColumns,
            "dom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"i>'
        });
```

Update:

I also tried with `"dom": 'lfrtip'`.

I was able to create the desired look using `"dom": '<"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6"f>>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">'` (which structure is automatically generated when removing the dom property). But still wondering why doesn't behave `'lfrtip'` the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With styling other than default, the default value for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) is changed, see [Styling](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Styling).

For example with Bootstrap framework, default value for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) is

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
```

Comment: I see now, thank you. So whenever I touch the dom parameter the styling will be changed as well, even when I don't add styling like `"dom": 'lfrtip'`. This last part is a bit illogical for me but I can live with it I think.